# Expected value of red balls in the box after $20$ drawings

Tags: probability

We have 50 white balls in a box. We draw them with replacement, one by one. If we draw a white ball, we colour it red and return it to the box. If we draw a red ball, we just put it back.
After 20 drawings, we have $X$ red balls. Find expected value of $X$ and Var(X).

So first let's see that $X$ has 20 possible values: from 1 to 20. $X=j$ means that j times there was a white ball drawn. But I guess computing expected value from definition is an horror.

Secondly, I thought about diving $X$ into easier events, like for instance $X = X_1 + ... + X_{20}$, where $X_i$ would be equal to $1$ if in i-th drawing we have a white ball and $0$ otherwise. But it makes my situation just slightly easier... I guess there is some idea that would make the computations far easier. Maybe someone here has an idea how to find $EX$ and $Var{X}$? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Give every ball a number and do it with $X=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{50}$ where
$X_{i}=1$ if ball with number $i$ gets red and $X_{i}=0$ otherwise.

Caution by calculation of variance: the $X_i$ are not independent.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer Sir? Thank you (ô‿ô)

Comment: @V-Moy The $X_{i}$ are identically Bernouilli-distributed rv's with parameter
$p=1-\left(\frac{49}{50}\right)^{20}=\mathbb{E}X_{i}$. Then $\mathbb{E}X=50\mathbb{E}X_{1}=50p$
and $Var\left(X\right)=50Var\left(X_{1}\right)+50\times49\times Cov\left(X_{1},X_{2}\right)$.
Here $Var\left(X_{1}\right)=p\left(1-p\right)$ and $Cov\left(X_{1},X_{2}\right)=\mathbb{E}X_{1}X_{2}-\mathbb{E}X_{1}\mathbb{E}X_{2}=P\left(X_{1}=X_{2}=1\right)-p^{2}$.
Actually the hardest part is finding $P\left(X_{1}=X_{2}=1\right)$.
Can you do that?

Comment: I know Bernoulli distribution but how come $p=1-\left(\frac{49}{20}\right)^{20}$?

Comment: @V-Moy By every draw there is a probability of $\frac{49}{50}$ that ball $1$ is *not* drawn. There are $20$ draws giving a probability of $(\frac{49}{50})^{20}$ that ball $1$ is *never* drawn. Then there is a probability of  $1-(\frac{49}{50})^{20}$ that it is drawn *at least once* (and is coloured red).

Comment: I don't know how to get $P(X_1=X_2=1)$. I tried to use the inclusion–exclusion principle, but it didn't work. (╥﹏╥) Could you explain it to me, please? Thanks

Comment: @V-Moy $P(X_{1}=X_{2}=1)=1-P(X_{1}=0)-P(X_{2}=0)+P(X_{1}=0\wedge X_{2}=0)$. Here $P(X_{1}=0)=P(X_{2}=0)=\left(\frac{49}{50}\right)^{20}$ and
$P(X_{1}=0\wedge X_{2}=0)=\left(\frac{48}{50}\right)^{20}$

Comment: Does $P(X_1=0\wedge X_2=0)=\left(\frac{48}{50}\right)^{20}$ mean: Probability of ball 1 and 2 white for 20 draws is never drawn?

Comment: @V-Moy Yes, it does. We are asked to stop our discussion here, and I will obey. If things are not clear yet, then you will have to post a question yourself. Good luck, youngster.

Comment: OK! Thank you very much for the explanation. +1 Sir d(^◡^)b

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** This is equivalent to asking "Out of 50 balls, we pick 20 with repetition. What is the number of distinct balls picked".

Are you familiar with the coupons problem?

Comment: Ahhh you're the guy on Brilliant! BTW, could you please elaborate your answer Calvin? Thank you (ô‿ô)